# Холостые стихи?

Tags: пунктуация, поэзия

«Ключевые слова» В.Л. Рабиновича к его же статье «Почерк и прочерк».  Вопроса два: о стиле (точно ли, что холостой?) и о необходимой, но опущенной запятой в последней строке (так ли она нужна?).

От нежной чуткости и щедрой милости

Вы подарили мне немного жимолости,

И пчелы по весне обжили заросли

Растений новых, смысл придав всему.

Свет медонос искрился в майской замяти,

Пчелиный рой гудел как бездна в омуте,

Всплывала капля меда из прапамяти —

Генетики ненарушимый план.

О живности сказал, теперь о доблести,

О подвигах, о славе и о молодости,

Об алфавите, в отроческой шалости

Слетевшем с неба на игральный стол.

Вразброс от центра разбрелась кириллица,

По краю вразнотык прошлась глаголица,

И только на околице латиницы

Почти осознанно бэ ru е ё жэ зэ.

И, наконец, про звукопись и живопись,

Про тайнопись, иконопись и лунопись,

И, как тут ни крути, весь мир есть светопись

В той капле мёда, светлой как печаль.

Comment: Да, холостой - с пропуском ожидаемой рифмы, а размер сохранён - ямб. Если б и его не было, был бы, вероятно, верлибр.

Comment: Я бы и запятую не ставила, здесь сравнение внутри обособленного оборота-прилагательного с зависимым словом и читается на одном дыхании, ударение больше на слово светлой..

Comment: А ведь полноценный ответ, Людмила?

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ по поводу запятой.**

В той капле мёда, светлой, как печаль.

Запятая, я думаю, нужна, это **обычное обособление сравнительного оборота**. (В других редакциях мне встречался обособленный оборот).

Оборот в виде исключения **может не обособляться**, если в осложненном предложении надо показать, к какому слову он относится.  Пример их Розенталя: Я почувствовал на моих волосах прикосновение слабой, **как лист** дрожавшей руки. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Также  сравнительный оборот внутри другого обособленного оборота не обособляется **при сильном управлении** (и отсутствии паузы) и обособляется (как обычно) в противном случае (если паузу можно сделать):

Непрочный снег слетел с деревьев, обнажив стволы, **позеленевшие как бронза**.

На самом дне, **сухом и жёлтом, как медь**,  лежат огромные плиты.

Comment: Благодарю. Только поправлю за ненужностью...

Comment: @shampar, После Вашей правки неясно, почему "как береза" не обособлен, а "как медь" обособлен

Comment: Простите, @М_Г, не уразумел — что за берёза. А о правке... После моей правки ушли лишь прописные, беспричинно торчащие в словах. Они — ударные... Так и что? Нет причин их было выделять, и тем более так. Если Jasmin не пояснит только, что имелось в виду.

Comment: @shampar, Да, я перепутал бронзу с березой, каюсь. А то, что хотела сказать Jasmin, я понял: постановка запятой зависит от интонации. Не скажу, что разделяю ее подход. И желательно, конечно, выражать свою мысль яснее.

Comment: Согласен, — что есть, то есть.

Comment: Прописными буквами было показано ударение:  на причастии позеленевшие не делается ударение и пауза после него отсутствует, ударение переносится на оборот. (Паузы и ударения связаны между собой). А если сделать паузу, то получится два однородных определения с перечислительной интонацией.